# How to do Parallel upload of parts of a file to dropbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I have large file. I want to upload it to dropbox. Since the file size is too much, I want to divide the file into multiple parts and upload few parts in parallel. So that if one part fails, I can retry upload for only that part.

Is there a way to do that with **dropbox-sdk.js** or any other method?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In java, you can use session uploader. "UploadSessionStartUploader" .

Not aware of the equivalent JS function

Comment: @ND003 I found the JS equivalent here https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload_session-start. 
But I'm not able to do parallel uploads of parts of a file.
Does "UploadSessionStartUploader" supports parallel uploads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to [dropbox-sdk-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js), you can upload a large file using upload sessions:

- [`filesUploadSessionStart`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesUploadSessionStart__anchor)
- [`filesUploadSessionAppendV2`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesUploadSessionAppendV2__anchor)
- [`filesUploadSessionFinish`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesUploadSessionFinish__anchor)

You can upload multiple different files in parallel using upload sessions, but you can only upload a single file's data serially. That is, for a single file, you can only upload one consecutive piece of data at a time.